# Please tell me the mistake in this haskell coe syntactically

Tags: haskell

```
typingConstraint capGamma i (App (Abs x tau t)t2) =
  ((Abs x tau t)
  ,t2(TypeVar ("T"++show (i+1)))
  ,(TypeArrow(TypeVar("T"++show i)),(TypeVar("T"++ show (i+1)))))
   where ((Abs x tau t),t2(TypeArrow tau1 tau2)) = typingConstraint capGamma i x
```

error message

> "parse error in pattern t2"

Comment: Can you format your question so that the code is displayed with its original whitespace? One way is to indent each line with exactly four spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Your question gives very little information about what is going on more broadly, so I'm not sure how to fix the problem. I can, however, see the syntax error.

```
where ((Abs x tau t),t2(TypeArrow tau1 tau2)) = typingConstraint capGamma i x
```

has a pattern to the left of `=` which uses a pattern variable `t2` as a function, applied to `(TypeArrow tau1 tau2)`, but such patterns are not permitted: matching such a pattern would mean figuring out what function `t2` is from one example of its use.

My guess is that you're missing a comma. It's hard to give better advice without more information. It would really help me (and probably you, too) if you could say what the type of `typingConstraint` is. That type will tell you which patterns are valid for matching its output.